# What type of neural network would work best for credit scoring?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Let me just start by saying I only took the undergrad AI class at school so I know just enough to be dangerous.

Here's the problem I'm looking to solve...accurate credit scoring is a key part to the success of my business. Currently we rely on a team of actuaries and statistical analysis to suss out patterns in the few dozen variables we track about each individual that indicate that they may be a low or high credit risk. As I understand it this is exactly the type of job that neural nets are great at solving, that is, finding high order relationships across many inputs that a human would likely never spot and then rendering a decision or output that is on average more accurate than what a trained human could do. In short, I want to be able to input your name, address, marital status, what car you drive, where you work, hair color, favorite food, etc in and get a credit score back.

My question is what type or architecture for a neural network would be best for this particular problem. I've done a bit of research and it seems I'm generating questions faster than I'm finding answers at this point. The best I've been able to come up with is some kind of generative deep neural network with multiple hidden layers where each layer is able to abstract one level beyond the previous one. Im assuming it's going to be feed-forward just because it seems to be the default. We have historical data on all previous customers including the information we used to make the initial score as well as data on what type of credit risk they actually turned out to be. This would seem to lend itself to unsupervised learning. Where I'm lost is in number of layers, how the layers are different from each other, size of each layer, connectedness of each of the perceptrons and so on. The more I dig the more I'm getting into research papers that are over my head so I just need some smart person to point me in the right direction

Does anyone have any ideas? Again, I don't need a thorough explanation just a general area I should focus on.

Comment: This seems to be a question for crossvalidated (http://stats.stackexchange.com/). For SO you should give us some code to look at and try to help.

Comment: Agreed. This would be very hard to answer. However, I'm curious about why you suggest this is should be approached in an unsupervised manner. If you have all the inputs and an actual outcome, why would you not want to make use of that for supervised learning?

Comment: On thinking about it more, I think that any "optimal" answer you do get is only going to lead to a gigantic leap in understanding. Start with numerical data only e.g. convert car to car value, and set yourself to build a bog standard feed-forward multilayer perceptron with a single hidden layer. You might be surprised at the results. Then you can look for any deficiencies, which might serve to direct your own path a bit more clearly. The area is so vast, approach it incrementally.

Comment: You're right that that this should be supervised learning given that we have all the data the customer gave us representing the input vector and the actual outcome of rating that customer the way we did representing the target vector. I guess I was thinking of going the unsupervised route because that's closer to the manual approach we use today. The current method is to identify categories of customers to target or avoid based on some combination of information they give us. For instance males customers under 25 who live alone are riskier than female customers over 25 who are married.

Comment: I was thinking maybe the neural net could identify new or perhaps more granular customer segments that we hadn't considered. One example I found was that we frown upon frequent telephone number changes as its an indicator that you can't maintain long term service agreements. However if we spot that these telephone changes correspond with address changes, now you're just a guy that likes to have a local number. Previously we might have written you off but now spotting that pattern we recognize that you're not as risky as we had previously thought.

Comment: I would still like feedback on the proposed answer by runDOSrun, who (I believe) gave the correct answer. What you suggest now is extracting data from the "black box". That is **much** more complex, but not unachievable. You need to work out the relative weight of each of the circumstances to give an overall score for somebody. It is perhaps best raised as a separate question, but my gripe with this site is that it can penalise people who express algorithms by word rather than code.

Answer (score 2):

This is supervised learning since you have actual data that can be labelled. It's also feedforward since you're not predicting time series but assigning scores. Further, you should probably just prepare your data (assigning credit scores manually or with some rough heuristic) and start experimenting with some tools before you invest time into implementing state-of-the-art architectures. A multi-layer-perceptron (MLP) with 1 hidden layer is a sufficient starting point for such a problem. From there on, you can train the network to generalize your credit assignment heuristic you began with.

You should know that most "new" architectures you probably read about while researching are dealing with much more difficult problems than credit scoring (speech/image/character recognition/detection). There is a collection of papers on the scenario of credit scoring / risk classification, so I'd recommend reshifting your focus from architectures to actual case studies (see e.g. [this paper](http://www.scirp.org/journal/PaperDownload.aspx?paperID=4587)). Just pick a recent paper with MLPs and apply their parameters. Start simple and improve the system incrementally (as @roganjosh stated).

Comment: I guess I underestimated the power of just one hidden layer. Examples I found that were closest to what I want to achieve all had multiple layers that each had a specific task in the process of producing a score. I was coming at the problem from the direction we currently use which is like a game of Plinko. Now when a customer comes in we hit them with cascading sets of rules designed to discriminate customers into similar risk categories. They come in, bounce around according to the rules, and drop out the bottom into a bucket and then we rate the bucket.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out more complex neural architecture but my main point is that it's hard to go around this topic too methodologically as at one point a heavy phase of tweaking and experimentation will have to begin anyway. We know from the universal approximation theorem that 1 hidden layer is "powerful enough" for most cases so it's a good start. Association rules are often used and it might still be worth not throwing it away (see hybrid architectures with NNs that work with rules). I think what's more important is the way you'll structure the data.

Comment: @user1776041 You did not reply to my comments directly with an @ so I did not see that you replied at all, sorry. I just stumbled upon this again. I wholeheartedly agree with this answer, you will be surprised what a simple network can achieve on this. Any feedback on how this went? :)